# Perform native SQL Query during Spring startup

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring and Hibernate with an automatically generated database (for that I have set `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` to `"update"` in the JPA configuration properties).

I also have a class annotated `@Configuration` with a `@PostConstruct` method that is called on application startup after the database has been created or updated. This is where I setup the database with some default data if it's empty (first launch).

I would like to execute some custom native SQL queries at this moment. These queries won't return anything, they're just configuration stuff (like creating additional indexes or extensions).

Currently I'm stuck on creating a `SessionFactory` in order to create a new Hibernate `Session`. I've tried auto wiring it, but it doesn't work :

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Gives me: `Field sessionFactory in ... required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.`

I understand that I probably need to configure it elsewhere, but I don't know where. Several answers on SO use an xml configuration file, but I'm not using any configuration file so I can't do it that way.

Is there a way Spring can create the `SessionFactory` with the appropriate configuration ?

Comment: You do know that "Session" has nothing at all to do with JPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to access SessionFactory. Please just put your scripts into a file src/main/resources/scripts/myscript.sql. You can then do the following with Spring:

```
@Component
public class Startup {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void runNativeSql() {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("scripts/myscript.sql");
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, resource);
        } catch (SQLException | ScriptException e) {
            //LOG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire the JPA `EntityManager` as:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

If you really need a Hibernate `Session` and are using using JPA 2.1, the `Session` can be obtained from the `EntityManager` as:

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I get an exception during bean creation : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available`